# Is there an online source for clipped verb forms?

Tags: tanach, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

It is wonderful to have pealim.com to look up verb forms, but as far as I know, it does not include clipped forms. Is there any online source that allows looking up clipped forms, or at least a site that has paradigmatic clipped verb tables?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean by ‘clipped’ but www.biblehub.com has verse-by-verse Hebrew roots listed for every single word in Tanach if that is the sort of thing that would help?

Comment: I'm looking for something that has a full conjugation for roots that change form after vav-prefix, for example, final-heh pa-al forms.

Comment: Oh, I see. Dictionary of Classical Hebrew does that but I don’t think it’s online. Lily Kahn’s guide to Biblical Hebrew grammar has verb tables for standard forms (eg final-heh roots) and is available as an ebook.

Answer (score 1):

AlHatorah has a digitized old Biblical Hebrew lexicon, as well as different rabbis commentaries on grammar including the radak, [here](https://mg.alhatorah.org/OlderLexicons/1980)

Comment: But doesn't seem to include clipped forms, presumably because it's not focused on Biblical

Comment: @rivkah i misunderstood your question. Try this

Comment: I was thinking Al HaTorah must have something. This is a nice resource, but still doesn't give verb tables, that I can see?

Comment: I suppose not... can you give an example?

Comment: for example, היה, which loses final ה in the imperfect after vav, or אמר, which changes vowels from yomar to yomer after vav. There are certainly resources that explain the changes, but they usually don't give a full conjugation. Nor is there any resource I can find that allows one to enter a verb root and see a table of the pausal/clipped forms, similar to pealim.com.

Comment: I understand now thanks. A similar question was asked [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4785). They didn't come up with much... It seems like it doesn't exist.